# Spring 3 Dependency Injcetion

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am using Spring3 with xml based configuration. 
The problem is when the IOC container starts it loads/caches all the properties/fields defined in com.dao.MyDAOFactory class. I want to tell spring that only load/cache specific properties/fields.

The bean declaration is given below

```
<bean  id="daoFactory" class="com.dao.MyDAOFactory" ></bean>
```

Can any one help me ?

Comment: What does it mean Spring *caches* fields/properties? All non-prototype beans are created on startup and dependencies are injected before bean is accessible. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: Actually in class com.dao.MyDAOFactory there are 100 class fields defined with their setter and getters. But i want to get some of them around 20. When spring container starts it loads all 100. I want to restrict spring that dont load all.

Comment: What makes you believe that Spring is caching any of these properties?

Comment: log says that                                                                     "Getting BeanInfo for class [com.dao.MyDAOFactory]                               Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [com.dao.MyDAOFactory]                                   Found bean property 'firstDAO'                                                   Found bean property 'secondDAO'"    and so on.. it loads all DAO's. Each DAO name is displayed in log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [lazy-init attribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init) to defer the loading of your beans, but eventually all of them will be loaded.

Also keep this in mind that if a non-lazy singleton bean depends on one or more lazy beans, the lazy beans will be loaded at startup.

Comment: For this i need to declare all beans in XML?

Comment: If you want all your beans to be lazy just add the attribute to the beans tag: `<beans default-lazy-init="true">`. If you want to add only to selected beans, you will have to add to each bean definition.